# How to handle conflicting files in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a recipe that includes on `mysql::server` but replaces my.cnf file. The result is that on each chef-client run it restarts mysql server because my.cnf was replaced twice during chef-client run. How to avoid that?

**Update:** yes, this happens because `mysql::server` deploys my.cnf and then my recipe overwrites it. The question is how to disable deployment of my.cnf by `mysql::server` without disabling or modifying this cookbook (by using only changes in my wrapper-cookbook). Directly modifying community cookbooks is considered a bad practice so there surely should be a way to achieve desired behaviour using wrapping cookbook.

Comment: Why was it replaced twice? Surely the answer to this is by making sure there's only one resource declaration that touches `my.cnf`.

Comment: I suggest using the mysql_config resource listed in the mysql cookbook: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/mysql

Comment: What cookbook are you wrapping around? The "official" `mysql` cookbook that @MarkO'Connor linked to does not include a `mysql::server` recipe (in fact, it has no recipes at all). Your best bet would probably be to switch to that and declare `mysql_service` and `mysql_config` resources in your wrapper.

Comment: I user an older version of this recipe. I think `mysql_config` resource will fix my problem. But is there some general way to deal with similar situations?

Comment: the mysql cookbook had a major update in v6.0 - they replaced all their recipes with LWRPs

Comment: The general way to deal with it is with a PR on the community cookbook.  Library cookbooks should provide you a way to override their template.  The latest mysql does that.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of this, you have two template resources being declared for your my.cnf and one of them needs to be disabled.

Without the recipes I can only guess but this commonly occurs when you include the `mysql::server` recipe (which has it's own template resource for my.cnf) and then you specify your own template resource for my.cnf.

The MySQL cookbook allows you to define extra configuration using `mysql_config` Resource

```ruby
mysql_service 'foo' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.5'
  initial_root_password 'change me'
  action [:create, :start]
end

mysql_config 'foo' do
  source 'my_extra_settings.erb'
  notifies :restart, 'mysql_service[foo]'
  action :create
end
```

You need to need to create `my_extra_settings.erb` in your cookbook